# prove for gradient difference of two hyperbola

Tags: geometry

I made a simulation using Geogebra that shows hyperbola with $a→0$ is less sensitive to noise δ than hyperbola with $a→c$. It is hard to use hyperbola equation so I use asymptote equation instead.
let us say that the asymptote of canonical hyperbola is determined as
$$y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{c^2-a^2}{a^2}}x $$
let us only take the gradient of the asymptote equation with the same $c$ and $\delta$, when $a_1 < a_2$ prove that
$$\frac {\sqrt{\frac{c^2-(a_1+\delta)^2}{(a_1+\delta)^2}}-\sqrt{\frac{c^2-a_1^2}{a_1^2}}}{\delta}<\frac {\sqrt{\frac{c^2-(a_2+\delta)^2}{(a_2+\delta)^2}}-\sqrt{\frac{c^2-a_2^2}{a_2^2}}}{\delta} $$
Thank you.

Comment: You have given a "hyperbolic context" but how is it connected to the inequality ? Is there a geometrical interpretation/motivation ? What is the "physical meaning of $\delta$ ? Besides, the numerators of the two big fractions being negative, you should write in a different way the inequality to be established...

Comment: I made a simulation using Geogebra that shows hyperbola with $a \to 0$ is less sensitive to noise $\delta$ than hyperbola with $a \to c$. It is hard to use hyperbola equation so I use asymptote equation instead.

Comment: Thanks. It make sense now.